# ARP ping to Device class

Tags: c#, networking, arp

I have some problem with my ARP pinging.

First I ping scan to find IP's on network. Then I do an ARP lookup to find MACs (and use a database to find vendors) and Hostnames (if the devices has any). Then I add it all to a Device class in a foreach loop, and display it in my GUI.

This is part of my foreach loop

```
if (SendARP(intAddress, 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) == 0) // ARP Success!
{
DoAlotOfStuff(IP,macAddr); // Adds Info to Device class
}
```

The above code doesn't work. If I add a Threaded sleep it doesn't work either, but if I add a

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("");
```

before the DoAlotOfStuff() I will have to press the "OK" button on the messagebox, but the loop works, and the devices gets added succesfully and shown in GUI.

Now what do I do? I think Timers might be a choice, but I am unsure as how to use them. Threaded sleep doesn't work since it pauses the GUI.

SendARP is Pinvoke

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern int SendARP( 
int DestIP, int SrcIP, byte[] pMacAddr, ref uint PhyAddrLen);
```

The DoAlotOfStuff function just uses the Device class Setters to set options such as IP,MAC,VENDOR and Hostname

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(IP).HostName;
```

EDIT: My entire Loop:

```
        foreach (Device d in Devices)
        {
            IPAddress Destination = IPAddress.Parse(d.GetIP());

            byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
            uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

            int intAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(Destination.GetAddressBytes(), 0);

            if (SendARP(intAddress, 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) == 0)
            {
                d.SetMAC(MacFormat(ByteArrayToString(macAddr)));

                d.SetVendor(CheckVendorList(d.GetIP(), ByteArrayToString(macAddr)));

                d.SetName(FindName(d.GetIP()));

                ADD_TO_LISTVIEW(d.GetAll());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What part of your code doesn't work? Have you stepped through it with a debugger? You have not included enough code for us to identify the problem

Comment: Read my question again. I've explained very detailed when it works and when it doesn't. None of my code is faulty, as I explain it works perfectly with a messagebox to delay code execution.

Comment: If none of your code is faulty then how do you have a problem? You should really include the code for `SendARP` and `DoAlotOfStuff`. How long did you try sleeping for? Sounds like `SendARP` is doing something asynchronously... again, have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, byte[] pMacAddr, ref uint PhyAddrLen);

Comment: I have added my entire Foreach loop. There are a lot of custom functions, but if it gives you better understanding